# How to get correct link for tax term if terms are translated with WPML?

Tags: wordpress, wpml

So far I had this code which worked nice for showing links to custom taxonomy terms.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($category->term_id, 'galerija-taxonomy'); ?>">
```

Then I translated terms in different languages with WPML and code doesn't work correctly anymore, it links to same as before (default language slug taxonomy).

How to format correct code for all languages to get correct term link?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<?php $term_link = get_term_link($category->term_id, 'galerija-taxonomy');?>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $term_link );?>"><?php _e('Maak een afspraak','yoursite'); ?></a>
```

For more information please refer: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I don't need to translate a string, I am looking for code which will echo correct link to the term. So instead of <a href=".../gallery/video"> for German I would get <a href=".../galleria/video">. Wordpress doesn't format link properly for WPML translation using default code

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is still the same

Comment: What you are getting in  "$term_link" variable?

Comment: If you need help please come on chat.